# Oracle Insert Date and Time into Date column [Stored Procedure]

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am using following function.

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Its working fine if I am updating data from a simple query like:--

```
set modified_on= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

**But not working in case of stored procedure.**

Note:- In stored procedure I am using dynamic query. Execute Immediate....

No error but only date getting inserted or updated not time.

Now:-- "31-07-2017"
Need Something like:-- "31-07-2017 hh:mi:ss"

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: If the column is date, why are you using to_char at all?

Comment: Because I am trying to insert time with date as I have mentioned.

Comment: Need Something like:-- "31-07-2017 hh:mi:ss"

Comment: Whatever problem you're having isn't to do with the date reformatting; despite using slightly different format masks that would work, though using `set modified_on = sysdate` would be fine and better as noted already. You may be doing something wrong in your dynamic SQL, so add your code for that to the question. From what you've shown so far it isn't obvious why you'd be using dynamic SQL at all though. It seems more likely you're just querying the inserted/updated value incorrectly. A date *always* has a time, even if it's midnight. Try `select to_char(modified_on, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS)` ?

Comment: @Alex I don't think "2016-05-27 00:00:00" this data is useful. I just run your query.

Comment: Trying it with a row in the table created today by your procedure would be rather more helpful; no idea how that old one was created. If you're sure that data created by the procedure also has the time set to midnight then add your dynamic code (or the whole procedure) to the question. Also check there are no triggers on the table.

Comment: Thanks Alex its working with newly added row. There is something wrong with my dynamic query.

Comment: If you want us to diagnose bugs in your dynamic SQL you need to **post the code in question**. Give us a fighting chance.

Comment: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')` can be replaced with `sysdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be going mad, but I'm sure this exact question has been posted verbatim before, in all its craziness. Anyway.. You wrote:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

This doesnt make sense. You have a date, you convert it to a string looking like one format and immediately try and convert it back to date, but using a different format. You can't do this: it doesnt make sense to take the date right now, and convert it to a string looking like `2017-JUL-31 18:28:00` and then ask oracle to interpret it using slashes and a numerical month - the string you just had it prepare has dashes, not slashes. It has a text month name not a numerical month identifier.. It won't work. Oracle will hit the first `-` and expect a `\` and it'll choke.

Just use the date you have to start with, as a date:

```
SYSDATE
```

i.e:

```
set modified_on= SYSDATE
```

Comment: But SYSDATE will return only date, I need time also.

Comment: Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm - "SYSDATE returns the current date **and time** set for the operating system on which the database resides"

Comment: Hi Caius,   With query its working but not for StoredProcedure. Can you please have a look into below example.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Uspx_test(x number) is
BEGIN
update x set modified_on= sysdate where xx=x;
 end Uspx_test;

Comment: What error message? If no error and you're just doing SELECT *( FROM table and seeing only date, check your query tool isn't formatting date as yy/mm/dd for example. Read for more info: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format.htm

Comment: @DineshJoshi - if `sysdate` only returned the date with no time, how would converting it to a string and back magically add the time?

Comment: @Alex only case of stored procedure. Please try to above example.

Comment: I am also surprised with this scenario that's  why need your help guys.

Comment: @DineshJoshi: `sysdate` **does** return the time. If you don't see it, then your SQL client simply doesn't display it.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, Current Date + Time = Sysdate. `select sysdate from dual` would produce `2017-07-31 23:18:40`

Comment: Can anyone give me any example.

Comment: like:-- CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Uspx_test(x number) is
BEGIN
update x set modified_on= sysdate where xx=x;
 end Uspx_test;